# How to echo and trim either end of a URL?

Tags: php, regex, echo, trim

I am trying to trim either end of a URL from the current pages address bar, I want to specify what's removed from the start of the URL and then leave the next folder then trim the end off completely, then capitalize the output and remove - (dashes) and replace them with a space. Quite a list of things...

So if the URL was

```
http://www.website.com/article/article-category/the-article.php
```

What I'd like to do is specify to trim **http://www.website.com/article/** from the start leave **article-category** then trim **/the-article.php** from the end.

Then out put **article-category** as **Article Category**

```
<?php $url="http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$url=str_replace('http://www.website.com/article/','',$url);
echo $url; ?>
```

So far this is what I have, it will remove the first part of the URL you ask it to. In this case it will remove **http://www.website.com/article/** but I do not know how to remove the the end section or capitalize and replace -'s with spaces.

I tried adding `ucfirst(strtolower` to uppercase the first letters but it gave an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the exact criteria are (how deep the path can be), but you can explode on `/`, pop of the last element of the array and put the rest together again:

```
$url=str_replace('http://www.website.com/article/','',$url);
$url_array = explode('/', $url);
$throw_away = array_pop($url_array);
$remaining = implode('/', $url_array);
```

But there are numerous solutions using php's string functions as well to find the last `/` and get the part of the string up until that last `/`.

Comment: hey @jeroen thanks for replying, however when I tried this it outputs nothing :S

Comment: @GoldenGonaz Your result is stored in remaining: http://codepad.viper-7.com/SPMp94